# How to prepend a JavaScript string to every module compiled by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I want to prepend a JavaScript string to every module required in my code and compiled by Webpack.

For example, if my `entry.js` file looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import $ from 'jquery';
import init from './init.js';

init();
```

I want my `output.js` bundle to consist of something like this:

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  // prepended JavaScript goes here

  // code for lodash module below
}

function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  // prepended JavaScript goes here

  // code for jquery module below
}

function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  // prepended JavaScript goes here

  // code for init.js module below
}

function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  // prepended JavaScript goes here

  var _lodash = __webpack_require__(1);
  var _jquery = __webpack_require__(2);

  init();
}
```

I tried writing a simple loader, and it worked, except that it didn't include modules from `node_modules` since I'm excluding those from my `/\.js$/` rule.

So I suspect I need to use a plugin. This is what I have so far:

```
var pluginName = "PrependJSPlugin";

var apply = (options, compiler) => {
  compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(pluginName, compilation =>
    compilation.hooks.afterOptimizeModules.tap(pluginName, modules => {
      modules.forEach(mod => {
        if (mod.resource !== void 0 && mod.resource.includes(".js")) {
          var contId = "__WBP_PREPEND__";
          var script = `
            ;var el = document.createElement('pre');
            el.innerHTML = '${mod.resource}';

            var container = document.getElementById('${contId}');
            if (!container) {
              container = document.createElement('div');
              container.id = '${contId}';
              container.appendChild(el);
              document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);
            } else {
              container.appendChild(el);
            }
          `;
          mod._source._value = script + mod._source._value;
        }
      });
    })
  );
};

module.exports = function(options) {
  return {
    apply: apply.bind(this, options)
  };
};
```

For the most part, it seems like it's appending it correctly but the compiled output is getting corrupted somehow and I see syntax errors all over the place. I'm definitely doing something I shouldn't be doing with that `_source` property.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

#### Why do I want to do this?

This is not something that will go into production. I'm trying to debug a PhantomJS v1 error occurring in a third party service I use for rendering a PDF from an Angular page. Yikes, I know!

I'm catching errors with `window.onerror` and appending it to the body so they're displayed in the rendered PDF. Unfortunately, the errors don't include source file nor line numbers. So I'm trying to display the name of every module before it runs hoping to see at which one the JavaScript stops executing.